# JMeter - Pass http response values to jdbc request without using xpath extractor?

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, sql, sql-injection

I'm using JMeter and I need to get the value of `<productid>` from an Http API response (productid = 001)[see Http API response screenshot] and pass it to a jdbc request [see JDBC request screenshot]. How do I do this without using xpath?

Http API response:

[image]

JDBC request:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with JMeter, so not posting as an answer, but can you use `String.Contains()` to find the `productid` tag position then `String.Substring()` to get the value? It's probably simpler than trying to get it via Regex (which a quick internet search says is supported by JMeter). There don't appear to be any plugins that would let you traverse an XML DOM without XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you don't like XPath Extractor you can always switch to [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), the relevant configuration would be something like:

- Reference Name: the same value you use in the XPath Extractor, i.e. `id`
- Regular Expression: `<productid>(.+?)</productid>`
- Template: `$1$`

You can refer it in the JDBC Request like:

- `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE id = ${id}`

or maybe

- `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID = '${id}'`

or use your approach but in this case you will need to know the data type of this ID column in the database.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with XPath Extraction? Is there a specific reason you cannot use XPath?

You can use RegEx extractor, but keep in mind you are going to have to build a pretty well structured query to get the right value. XPath anticipates many results and puts them into an index array.

Without more information this question cannot be answered. - Why is that 90% of the questions in the SQA section?